# How to access Azue certificate from local system in c# application

Tags: azure

I need to call some API of an application from some other application using certificate authentication.
I can access local application certificate using StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=83D2CEE781FC8D7E6C5372433CBACA75F9BC4B34

But I am not able to access the certificate of application which is hosted in Azure.

Can you please suggest how to access certificate parameters from Azure like StoreName and StoreLocation from my local application?

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate what you mean with hosted in Azure? App Services, Container, AKS, VM, etc?

For App Services there is an option you might want to give a shot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-windows-apps

You can also store certificates in KeyVault and access those securely - but this would require code changes. [Example for secrets, but works similar for certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)

If you want 100% the same way it works currently, you will need to stick with VMs.